Narrow frequency response when connecting the microphone to a certain USB port directly
These are the USB ports in my HP EliteBook (from the manual):


When I connect my Q2U mic directly to the port denoted as 10, I get nothing above 4 KHz. If I connect it to the same port, but through the splitter (to which my keyboard and mouse are connected), it produces 10 KHz or more depending on the mic's position. If it's connected to the port denoted as 11, either directly or through the splitter, it also produces 10 KHz or more.
How could this be explained? Is this normal, or a problem with the ports, or a problem with the mic?

This could be due to USB versions not beeing totally compatible. I have seen similar problems in other cases when connecting older devices to modern computers. The microphone has an older implementation of USB, witnessed by the type of connector. A relatively modern PC has a newer version of USB. It is supposed to work and be compatible, but sometimes does not. If you connect through a USB hub*) it might be "happier" with the older USB device and making it work.
*) Technically it is not a "splitter" but a hub. The hub contains a microcomputer and may do translations of USB protocol versions between the up and down connections. The exact details of this are a bit above my head though.

Then how does it work when connected directly to port 11?

@AlwaysLearning Good question. Probably the microphone USB implementation has a bug in the software which only surfaces in certain configurations. The two ports on the laptop are clearly different implementations of USB as one is notated as (Charging). The USB protocol is quite a complicated thing and to me it is more like magic that it works at all.

Would you return the microphone?

@AlwaysLearning Return or not? Your choice. If it works for you, then keep it. It is not the best mic ever, nor is it a bad mic as I understand it. Bander, who I usually trust, has done a review. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjCJbhjFYiA
